# DELETE and INSERT - is this simple query statement sufficient to preserve atomicity?

Tags: postgresql

I intend to update a table by going for a `DELETE` then `INSERT` on **postgres** in a single query. Obviously I want the `DELETE` to only take place if the `INSERT` is successful, i.e. preserve atomicity.

Is writing the query as below, sufficient for this?

```
DELETE FROM table_one WHERE some_id = 1;
INSERT INTO table_one(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3), (val4, val5, val6), ...
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

After [reading around](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm), I believe I am supposed to use transactions. Is this correct?

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM table_one WHERE some_id = 1;
INSERT INTO table_one(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3), (val4, val5, val6), ...
COMMIT;
```

So if `DELETE` fails, then the entire transaction fails?

Comment: That's the entire idea of a transaction: either **all** statements succeed or none.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use transactions.

And yes if one of transaction statements fails all of it will rollback. Meaning : Nothing will happen or everything will be done.

> Your code :

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM table_one WHERE some_id = 1;
INSERT INTO table_one(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3), (val4, val5, val6), ...
COMMIT;
```

See following link for more information about transactions: [Transactions in PostgreSql](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions)